# Asynchronous AJAX call is putting my iterators out of whack

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I use the following AJAX request to retrieve a number of pages, whose titles I have in an array called `pages`. Each response goes into a separate div, and I want to give each of those divs an id the same as the page title.

Of course, by the time my requests come back, `[i]` has reached `pages.length` and all my div names are `undefined`.

```
for ( i = 0; i < pages.length; i++ ) {
  $.ajax({
    //async:false makes it work but it slows things down too much
    url: 'ajax_' + pages[i],
    success: function(data) {
      $('<div id="' + pages[i] + '">' + data + '</div>').appendTo('div.content');
      }
  });
 }
```

How can I achieve a good lockstep between requesting and responding variables?

Thanks!

**NB** I would rather keep it asynchronous (i.e. not use `async:false`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax_' + pages[i],

    context: i, // set `this` to `i` in the callback

    success: function(data) {
        // `this` is the correct, "frozen" `i`
        $('<div id="' + pages[this] + '">' + data + '</div>').appendTo('div.content');
    }
});
```

Note that `this` is always coerced into an object - like `new Number(2)` instead of `2`. Nevertheless they can be used to access array indices.

There are cleaner ways to do this, like creating a closure, but this may work fine for you (i.e. if you aren't using `this` for anything else in the callback).

Comment: interesting. and clever. and works. except for on the 0th element...?

Comment: could this be because `new Number(0)` is `undefined`? -- sorry! scratch that, it's not...

Comment: Ah yes, `0` is "falsy" and jQuery will act as if it is `undefined`. Try `context: new Number(i)` instead.

Comment: Looking at it, you might want to use `context: pages[i]` instead to make it a little bit more semantical (`this` is then really a page).

Comment: even better. tbh context itself is quite exciting.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the var keyword in your for loop variables to properly scope them.  Otherwise this loop is accessing a global variable called i, which might or might not clash with another loop.

But that's not the solution to the exact problem you have.  You need to cache a reference to the current page and use that in the ajax response.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++ ) {
  var page = pages[i];
  $.ajax({
    //async:false makes it work but it slows things down too much
    url: 'ajax_' + page,
    success: function(data) {
      $('<div id="' + page + '">' + data + '</div>').appendTo('div.content');
      }
  });
 }
```

Comment: thanks for this, but sadly when the callback comes in, `page` is set to the last value in the array

Comment: this will suffer from a similar problem.  declaring 'var page' inside the loop doesn't give it a new scope, unlike other languages like C#.  JavaScript has lexical scoping, not block scope.  page has the same scope as *everything* inside that function

Comment: bah, you're right.  $.each(pages, function(i, page){}) instead of the for loop would work though right?  Since you're introducing a new function into the mix?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has something called lexical scope, which is different from block scope that most are familiar with.  In JS, to give something a new scope, it has to be inside another function, not just curly braces { }.

The reason why async: false works is because you are forcing it to wait for the response before moving on, which avoids your scope issue.

Try this:

```
for ( i = 0; i < pages.length; i++ ) {
    $.ajax({
        //async:false makes it work but it slows things down too much
        url: 'ajax_' + pages[i],
        success: (function(index){ 
              return function(data) {
                  $('<div id="' + pages[i] + '">' + data + '</div>').appendTo('div.content');
              };
        })(i)
    });
}
```